# Laravel 5.1 - datatables -Adding a link using editColumn

Tags: laravel, datatables

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with datatables (yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle).
I want to add a link to the data in my table but its not working. I guess the problem is the manner i put the parameter, it should be different.

PS: When I remove the parameter, it works and show me the link: categorie/afficher

```
public function anyData()
{
  $categories = \App\Categorie::all();
  return Datatables::of($categories)
           ->editColumn('nom', '<a href="'.route('categorie-afficher', $id).'" >{{$nom}}</a>')
           ->make(true);
}
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/categorie/afficher/{id}', [
    'as' => 'categorie-afficher',
    'uses' => 'CategorieController@afficher'
]);
```

The program give an error: undefined $id. When I put an integer value instead of $id, it works!

```
 ->editColumn('nom', '<a href="'.route('categorie-afficher', 1).'">{{$nom}}</a>')
```

Comment: I think you're missing a colon after  $id).' " should be  $id).' " '

Comment: Thanks, but no. That's not the problem. The colons are ok :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [generating URLs To Named Routes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes). In your case it should be:

```
->editColumn('nom', '<a href="{{ route("categorie-afficher",["id"=>$id]) }}" >{{$nom}}</a>')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. It gives [Undefined variable: id]. it works when i put an integer instead of $id:  ->editColumn('nom', '<a href="'.route('article-afficher', 1).'">{{$nom}}</a>')

Comment: @Keyser_Soze Sorry, you are right. I have updated answer. Just,  like in other blade views - wrap it with {{ route(...) }}.

Comment: thanks! this is the final code:  ->editColumn('nom', '<a href=" {{route(\'categorie-afficher\', $id)}}">{{$nom}}</a>')

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
->rawColumns(['name'])
```

after edit